# How to solve when Django views.py is not passing the dictionary value to html?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I have a dictionary value in views.py and rendering it to front end. When I loop through the dictionary in html, only one value is showing while other values are not. What could be the issue for this?

## views.py

```
def Student_Create(request):
    form = Student_Model_Form(request.POST or None)
    # get class names and days
    classes = Create_Class.objects.all()
    cls = {}
    for i in classes:
        cls[i] = {
            'class_name': i.class_name,
            'from_day': str(i.from_days),
            'to_day': str(i.to_days),
            'from_time': i.from_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
            'to_time': i.to_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
        }
    print(cls)
    template_name = 'genius/students_create.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'classes': cls}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

## student.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select-class">Select Class</label>
  <select class="custom-select" multiple name="select-class">
     {% for i in classes%}
      <option value="{{i.class_name}}">{{i.class_name}} : {{i.from_day}}-{{i.to_day}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

And the final output is like this.

[See The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1SNO.png)

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then creating dict like above. You can do
views.py

```
def Student_Create(request):
    form = Student_Model_Form(request.POST or None)
    # get class names and days
    classes = Create_Class.objects.values_list('class_name', 'from_days', 'to_days' ,'from_time', 'to_time', flat=True)
    template_name = 'genius/students_create.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'classes': classes}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: This could be bette solution with less code. Thanks!

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari you can upvote or accept the solution.

Comment: I do accept the solution. I can't upvote cause of low reputation i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list for storing the data:

```
...
cls = []  # Change from dict to list.
for i in classes:
    cls.append({
        'class_name': i.class_name,
        'from_day': str(i.from_days),
        'to_day': str(i.to_days),
        'from_time': i.from_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
        'to_time': i.to_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
    })
...
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forget about the list. Thank you